# Correct way of applying material design to checkbox on old devices

Tags: android, material-design

I have a checkbox that on Lollipop devices looks like material design guildelines suggest. However, when I open this check box on old android devices, it looks like a default checkbox there.

What is the right way of making sure ALL standard components look on old (14+) android versions same as in Lollipop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use support libraries and **android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
 android:id="@+id/checkbox_id"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:textColor="@color/white"
/>
```